# Marketing cloud Mobile Push app connection

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sfdcmobilesdk-android, sdk

I'm currently connecting my client's app into MobilePush to send push notifications.

I've added APNs.p8 Auth Key, Key ID, Team ID, Bundle ID. For both IOS & Android, it seems enabled as below.

[image]

1. What should I do to proceed the next step? (Is it adding SDK? - there is another person in charge for this app development. What should i ask them to do?)
2. Can you please guide me the process for proceeding the rest of implementing moblie push?

I've checked below link to get some ideas, but haven't understood well.

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/
https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/apple.html

Thank you

Comment: Correct. Follow the documentation you linked.

Comment: Can you please guide me on the next steps ?